# Firebase sorting and filtering

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to filter blog entries through url params containing the url property of its categories array.

```
http://example.com/blog.html?filter="foo-bar"
```

I want to list every entry that has the filter param in its categories array url value.

This is the entry composition.

```
  - Title
  - Content
  - Categories
     -[0]{Name: "foo bar", Url: "foo-bar"}
     -[1]{Name: "Other", Url: "other"}
```

How would this be achieved?

I´ve tried a couple of things with `orderByChild('categories').equalTo(...)` but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Firebase and other NoSQL database structures, there is a practice called **denormalization** that helps with sorting and filtering. The basic idea is to have the same data in multiple formats, designed for a specific task. So in your case, you might have something like this:

```
blogEntries: {
  blogId1: {
    Title: '...',
    Content: '...',
    Categories: [ 'categoryId1', 'categoryId2', ... ]
  },
  ... more blog entries ...
}
blogCategories: {
  categoryId1: {
    Name: '...',
    Url: '...'
  },
  ... more categories ...
},
blogEntriesByCategories: {
  'foo bar': [ blogId1, blogId5, ... ],
  'other': [ blogId3 ],
  ...
}
```

You would then do your search on `blogEntriesByCategories` to get all the blog IDs where it matches `'foo bar'` for example, then cross reference those IDs with the data under `blogEntries` that match the respective blog ID.

With Firebase 3, you can write to multiple paths simultaneously. So any time you add, update, or delete a blog entry you would also update `blogEntriesByCategories`. This [blog entry](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86.html) has a great write up on how that is done with Firebase 3.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great explanation! I'll look into it. Thanks